# AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types

Tags: c#, automapper

I have following classes in my solution:

```
    public class VehicleMakeEntity
    {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }

      public ICollection<VehicleModelEntity> VehicleModels { get; set; }
    }

    public class VehicleModelEntity
    {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }

      public Guid VehicleMakeId { get; set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }

      public VehicleMakeEntity VehicleMake { get; set; }
    }


    public class VehicleMake : IVehicleMake
    {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }

      public ICollection<IVehicleModel> VehicleModels { get; set; }
    }

    public class VehicleModel : IVehicleModel
    {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }

      public Guid VehicleMakeId { get; set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }

      public IVehicleMake VehicleMake { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have following interfaces:

```
public interface IVehicleMake
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    ICollection<IVehicleModel> VehicleModels { get; set; }
}

public interface IVehicleModel
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }

    Guid VehicleMakeId { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    IVehicleMake VehicleMake { get; set; }
}
```

My AutoMapper configuration is like this:

```
            AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
              cfg.CreateMap<VehicleMakeEntity, VehicleMake>().ReverseMap();
              cfg.CreateMap<VehicleMakeEntity, IVehicleMake>().ReverseMap();
              cfg.CreateMap<IVehicleMake, VehicleMake>().ReverseMap();
              cfg.CreateMap<VehicleModelEntity, VehicleModel>().ReverseMap();
              cfg.CreateMap<VehicleModelEntity, IVehicleModel>().ReverseMap();
              cfg.CreateMap<IVehicleModel, VehicleModel>().ReverseMap();
            });
```

When I try to do something like this:

```
var makes = Context.VehicleMakes.AsQueryable();

var vehicleMakes = await makes.Include(m => m.VehicleModels).ToListAsync();

return new List<IVehicleMake>(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<VehicleMake>>(vehicleMakes));
```

I get the mapping type error: VehicleModelEntity -> IVehicleModel.

I suppose I didn't created my mappings correctly. How should I configure my mappings to avoid this?

Comment: Check whats the inner exception in the error.

Comment: I added following mapping to configuration: cfg.CreateMap<List<VehicleMakeEntity>, List<VehicleMake>>().ReverseMap();  and I don't get any error anymore but the list doesn't get populated, it's empty so the problem is not solved.

Comment: Also, when I remove "Include(m => m.VehicleModels)" when retrieving makes, then the mapping works.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use Ninject to dynamically load mapping configuration like this:                                                                 public class DIModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
        //Automapper initialization//
        }
    }                                                                                              Could that be the problem?

Answer (score -1):

The mapping configuration seems correct. The [QueryableExtensions.ToListAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync(v=vs.113).aspx) method returns a `Task<List<T>>`, try passing `vehicleMakes.Result` in your mapping.